# Refinance Car Loan

Tags: loans, interest-rate, refinance

Refinance Question Car Loan:

Two years ago, you purchased a $20,000 car, putting $4,000 down and borrowing the rest. Your loan was a 36-month fixed rate loan at a stated rate of 6.0% per year. You paid a non-refundable application fee of $100 at that time in cash. Interest rates have fallen during the last two years and a new bank now offers to refinance your car by lending you the balance due at a stated rate of 5.0% per year. You will use the proceeds of this loan to pay off the old loan. Suppose the new loan over the residual loan life requires a $200 non-refundable application fee. Given all this information, should you refinance? How much do you gain/lose if you do?

1. Yes, gain $30.32
2. No, lose $30.32
3. No, lose $169.68
4. Yes, gain $169.68

Can anyone explain how to do this question? I am not getting any of these answers when completing the questions.

Thanks!

Comment: For this and your other question, you could work out the full amortization schedule to see the difference in the two scenarios. There's not a formula that you can apply easily to get the right answer.

Comment: "I am not getting any of these answers when completing the questions." What answer are you getting, and how are you getting there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Step 1:  Figure out where you are now.  You are 2 years into a three year loan, what is the balance?

Step 2:  Figure out how much interest you will pay if you stick with the existing loan.

Step 3:  Figure out how much interest you will pay if you refi.  A one year loan at 5% for the balance in step 1.  The add $200.

Step 4: Compare.

The most difficult part is step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
PV = principal
i  = periodic rate
m  = number of periods
d  = periodic payment

d  = PV i (1 + 1/((1 + i)^m - 1))           Formula 1
```

the balance `b` remaining in month `x` is

```
b  = (d + (1 + i)^x (i PV - d))/i           Formula 2
```

Applying your figures

$4000 is paid down, plus $100 in cash, requiring a loan of $16000

```
  PV =  16000
  i  =  0.06/12
  m  =  36

∴ d  =  PV i (1 + 1/((1 + i)^m - 1))  =  486.75
```

Balance after two years

```
  x  =  24
∴ b  =  (d + (1 + i)^x (i PV - d))/i  =  5655.53
```

Refinancing the balance

```
  PV =  b
  i  =  0.05/12
  m  =  12

∴ d  =  PV i (1 + 1/((1 + i)^m - 1))  =  484.16
```

Original remaining payments less new ones

```
(486.75 * 12) - (484.16 * 12 + 200)  =  -168.92
```

You would lose $168.92 by refinancing.  Close enough to option 3.

***Formulae***

1. Formula for periodic payment - [loan payment formula](http://financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html)

[image]

2. Formula for loan balance - [inhomogeneous difference equation](http://people.math.aau.dk/~cornean/IMM_E12/notes2011a.pdf) (Arne Jensen, Aalborg Uni.)

[image]